# USING DB2 MERGE :: Error Code: -788, SQL State: 21506

Tags: sql, merge, sql-update, db2

**Requirement:**

**Input Tables:** `csscustomertest` < `CUSTOMERCID` is PK> , `CHILDDETAILS` < `CUSTOMERCID` is FK>

**Input:**
`CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME`: Mary

**Output:** `CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME`: Mchildfirst0215

where 0215 is the date of birth (MMDD) from the `csscustomertest` table

I have used this statement to update `CHILDDETAILS`

```
merge into CHILDDETAILS 
  using ( 
    select 
      CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID,
      concat(
        trim(concat(substr(coalesce( CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME,''),1,1), 'childfirst')),
        concat(
          trim(coalesce(substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 6,2),'Mx')),
          trim(coalesce(substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 9,2),'Dx'))                
        )
      )   as    childfirst     
    FROM 
      csscustomertest 
    inner join 
      CHILDDETAILS  
    on ( csscustomertest.CUSTOMERCID = CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID )  
  )  CUST 
on ( CUST.CUSTOMERCID = CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID )  
when matched   then 
  update set CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME=CUST.childfirst
```

Got this error:

> [Error Code: -788, SQL State: 21506]  The same row of target table
>   "DB2ADMIN.CHILDDETAILS" was identified more than once for an update,
>   delete or insert operation of the MERGE statement.. SQLCODE=-788,
>   SQLSTATE=21506, DRIVER=3.57.82

Also tried using this query:

```
UPDATE 
  CHILDDETAILS 
SET 
  FIRSTNAME=(
    select 
      concat(
        trim(concat(substr(coalesce( CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME,''),1,1), 'childfirst')),
        concat(
          trim(coalesce(substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 6,2),'Mx')),
          trim(coalesce( substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 9,2),'Dx'))                
        )
      )   as    childfirst   
    FROM 
      csscustomertest 
    inner join 
      CHILDDETAILS  
    on ( csscustomertest.CUSTOMERCID = CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID ) 
    WHERE 
      CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID=220833
  ) 
WHERE  
  CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID=220833;
```

Getting a similar error:

> [Error Code: -811, SQL State: 21000]  The result of a scalar
>   fullselect, SELECT INTO statement, or VALUES INTO statement is more
>   than one row.. SQLCODE=-811, SQLSTATE=21000, DRIVER=3.57.82

I think I cannot update the same table in above query, may be I need to write a cursor. Appreciate any advise.

Comment: how many rows does `select * from csscustomertest where customercid = 220833` return?

Comment: @Laurence -- I think the error message suggests that it is `CHILDDETAILS` that contains more than one row for `CUSTOMERCID=220833`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for prompt inputs. I am able to resolve the problem.

**Cause of the above issue:** One to many relation  between csscustomertest and CHILDDETAILS table.

**Resolution:** Added below clauses in the query.

merge into CHILDDETAILS 
   using ( 
               select **CHILDDETAILS.CHILDCID**, CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID,CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME,CHILDDETAILS.LASTNAME,
            concat(
                             trim(concat(substr(coalesce( CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME,''),1,1), 'childfirst')),
                            concat(
                                                    trim(coalesce(substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 6,2),'Mx')),
                                                    trim(coalesce( substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 9,2),'Dx'))
                                          )
                   )   as    childfirst
           FROM csscustomertest inner join CHILDDETAILS  on ( csscustomertest.CUSTOMERCID = CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID )
                   where  CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID=220833
         )  CUST 
     on ( CUST.CUSTOMERCID = CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID **and  CUST.CHILDCID=CHILDDETAILS.CHILDCID**)

when matched  AND CUST.CUSTOMERCID=220833
   then update set CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME=CUST.childfirst;

**Code:**

```
merge into CHILDDETAILS 
   using ( 
           select CHILDDETAILS.CHILDCID, CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID,CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME,CHILDDETAILS.LASTNAME,
        concat(
                         trim(concat(substr(coalesce( CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME,''),1,1), 'childfirst')),
                        concat(
                                                trim(coalesce(substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 6,2),'Mx')),
                                                trim(coalesce( substr( cast(csscustomertest.dob as char(10) ), 9,2),'Dx'))                
                                      )
               )   as    childfirst    
       FROM csscustomertest inner join CHILDDETAILS  on ( csscustomertest.CUSTOMERCID = CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID )  
               where  CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID=220833
     )  CUST 
 on ( CUST.CUSTOMERCID = CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID and  CUST.CHILDCID=CHILDDETAILS.CHILDCID)  

when matched  AND CUST.CUSTOMERCID=220833
   then update set CHILDDETAILS.FIRSTNAME=CUST.childfirst;
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the `merge` statement is the way to go here.

Your problem is that the source query for the update (the one within `using(...)`) is returning more than one row with the same `CHILDDETAILS.CUSTOMERCID`.

Either `CHILDDETAILS` or `csscustomertest` has more than one row per customer.

You could simply use `DISTINCT` on the source query if the duplication is in `csscustomertest`.

If the duplication is in `CHILDDETAILS`, you may need to use `group by` and come up with a rule for which details you select.  However, I would think duplicate rows in `CHILDDETAILS` would probably be a problem with your data that needs to be resolved.

Comment: Child table is is having more then 1 record for each customer table. Thanks for the input, I am able to resolve the problem by adding clause and  CUST.CHILDCID=CHILDDETAILS.CHILDCID.. Complete query added as a answer