# SQL Merge Duplicate Records

Tags: sql, merge, db2-400

I'm trying to merge two tables in DB2 SQL, it keeps giving me the SQL State 21506 and error message SQL0788.

This is what I have so far:

```
merge into table1 as tgt
using table2 as src
on src.key1 = tgt.key1 and src.key2 = tgt.key2
when matched then
   update set
      (fld1, fld2, fld3) = (src.fld1, src.fld2, src.fld3)
when not matched then
   insert (fld1, fld2, fld3) values (src.fld1, src.fld2, src.fld3)
```

I searched for duplicates like this:

```
select src.key1, src.key2, count(*)
from table1 as tgt
inner join table2 as src on tgt.key1 = src.key1 and tgt.key2 = src.key2
group by src.key1, src.key2
having count(*) > 1
```

With no (duplicate) records returned.
What am I missing?

Comment: @Abra I searched for duplicates because is what the error message implies. That there is duplicate records.

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245315/using-db2-merge-error-code-788-sql-state-21506

Comment: No, I've been there, his problem was setting the relation wrong, I'm setting the relation right. Thanks though. I've been searching for the problem for quite some time now (around 6 hours). Looked everywhere with no answers, that's why I decided to post this question.

Comment: Join me in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218891/sql-merge-duplicate-records)

Answer (score 0):

SQLSTATE 21506 means [that](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzala/rzalaccl.htm#cc__classcode21)

> The same row of the target table was identified more than once for an
> update, delete, or insert operation of the MERGE statement.

So you've got two rows in SRC with the same keys...

You're not finding them with this statement

```
select src.key1, src.key2, count(*)
from table1 as tgt
inner join table2 as src on tgt.key1 = src.key1 and tgt.key2 = src.key2
group by src.key1, src.key2
having count(*) > 1
```

Because of the inner join, meaning the duplicate rows in table2 don't have a match in table1.

This should show them to you..

```
select src.key1, src.key2, count(*)
from table2 as src
group by src.key1, src.key2
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you, I actually did that before going for the inner join, but no (duplicate) records returned. Check the answer I posted, would you know why it worked?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was in the `update`.

Instead of:

```
update set
   (fld1, fld2, fld3) = (src.fld1, src.fld2, src.fld3)
```

Did in this way:

```
update set
   fld1 = src.fld1,
   fld2 = src.fld2,
   fld3 = src.fld3
```

Without changing anything else, this worked, now why? Still don't know...

Comment: If that's really the case, it would be a bug.  What version of IBM i?  Are you up-to-date on PTFs?

Comment: @Charles V7R2M0, unfortunately can't check regarding PTF's.

Comment: But not sure if it's a bug, in the IBM Knowledge Center for IBM i V7R1, the only example of a merge with a multiple row update is in the more verbose form. While, for example, DB2 for windows is in the less verbose form in multiple examples.